# what is the phantom pdf A4 size in pixel?

Tags: phantomjs

Actually i am using getting final output pdf A4 with help of phantom.I'm having content of **exact A4 size(595 * 842 pixels)**.But phantom pdf output is larger than A4(595 * 842 pixels) size.

Does anybody know???please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

you can actually use PhantomJS method paperSize. You will be able to specify page size width, height, format and much more. Here is a link for you: http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/property/paper-size.html